# How to auto width and height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making app with Android Studio and want to auto set width and height of image that I am showing on front page. my code is like this

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="375dp"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/japuji"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

this is the scrollview and when i set fill_parent, wrap_content in TextView its not working either, when i test it on big screen images are small ,

i have tried all like changing width to fill_parent and wrap_content

Comment: There's no image in the code you posted, so we have no idea what's going wrong.  Unless you mean the TextView, in which case why are you using a TextView to display an image instead of an ImageView?  There are things like scaleType that only work on ImageViews.

Comment: "i have tried all like changing width to fill_parent and wrap_content" Changing width of which element?

Answer (score 2):

You should not display an image as a background of a view, instead, you should use ImageView

```
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/imagedesc"
        android:id="@+id/my_image"

        android:src="@drawable/your_image" 

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
```

**src** : sets the image drawable

**scaleType** : sets the desired scale type, in this case **fitCenter** with **adjustViewBounds** set to **true** and **width** or **height** (one of them) to **wrap_content** will show the full image.

**EDIT** : 
if you have a fixed view size and you want to cover it all with that image drawable, you should use **centerCrop** as a **scaleType** instead of **fitCenter**

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently displaying the image (`android:background="@drawable/japuji"`) in the TextView, but the TextView has its height and width hard-coded: `android:layout_width="375dp" android:layout_height="220dp"`

Instead set the TextView's height and width to `match_parent`.

Comment: Define "didn't work": what was the result, and how did it differ from what you wanted?